# Android app development on PowerBuilder

Tags: android, powerbuilder

Anyone know if its possible to develop android apps with PowerBuilder.
Haven't found much regarding this on Google, which might mean that it isn't, but still want to hear the opinion of ppl at stackoverflow.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

right now I think the only possibility is Appeon Mobile for PowerBuilder. This is a beta version and it is supporting iOS right now, but in several months it will be capable for building native android and Windows Phone app too.

http://www.appeon.com/list.do?fid-60-page-1.htm

I hardly waiting it also :)

Br. Gábor

Answer (score 0):

One other possible solution I've considered but it is NOT a trivial solution.  Look at IIS modules and handlers in the MSDN.  Basically you can write a handler in PB.NET that will be used in IIS to create HTML5 that will run in just about any browser including mobile.

You then could assign a certain file type (e.g .powerbuilder ) which will be processed by your custom handler that was written in PB.NET.

Might be a good open source project.